# Unknown Balfa Road Bike

Tags: road-bike, frames, identify-this-bike, vintage

I have a Balfa road bike which I cannot find any information on or pictures anywhere.
I would like some help identifying the bike model, the original parts, and the frame.

What I have found so far:

1. Cycles Balfa was founded in the early 1990 and based out of Canada. Cycles Balfa was sold to Procycle group in 2001.
2. Balfa BB7 mountain bike was the jewel bike of the company and looked to be the prime focus of the company.
3. 2006 was the last BB7 produced by Procycles group and the Balfa name was no longer used.

Pictures of the Balfa road bike:
[image]

[image]

I have yet to see any road bikes made by either company. 
Any thoughts?

Comment: Looks gorgeous!   You might find info by searching the unofficial Balfa   "non mtb" forum at http://www.balfa.wooyek.pl/forum/viewforum.php?f=3

Comment: Thanks Criggie. Unfortunately the forum seems to be inactive and very little information available nowadays.

Comment: Wow!!! I had never seen one of those. I had a BB7 and a 2Step. I was a bike Balfa junkie 14 years ago.

Comment: Take some more photos of the joints of the frame and the bottom bracket.  You may have a bike with Balfa stickers on it. The head tube looks Balfa but the rest of the bike does not. They always made their own dropouts and those in that frame are not custom made. The lugs in the frame also makes me suspicious. Balfa never brazed anything. Other option is someone at Balfa made it as a personal bike.

Comment: @Brady, I think you may be right. It seems weird not to be able to find anything on the bike on the web. It would be pretty cool if it is a Balfa personal bike. I'll try and upload a few more pictures soon, so you can see the entire frame.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Brifters plus quill stem suggests around 1997 or 1998 vintage.

The rear brake bridge formed like a front fork, instead of two full seat stays up to the seat post... that's quite unusual.   Makes the smallish frame look even smaller.

I'd guess its a 7, maybe 8 speed on the rear, can't see in the photos.

The front fork has relatively little rake (curve) on the legs compared to older bikes, which also suggests late 90s.

That's a gorgeous bike - you should look after it and will enjoy riding it.

Comment: Interesting stuff! I appreciate your knowledge on the matter.

Comment: Unfortunately, the frame is really to small for myself or the intended person I got it for. it's a really fun bike, so I am looking to pass it along to someone that will fit it better.